# User leaving channel

Tags: getstream-io

Like other personal messenger, a user might want to organise chat channels they no longer wish to participate in by leaving the channel.

In Getstream sense, it would be removing the user from the channel's member list.

There does not seem to be a functionality for this.

I have tried to include removeMembers permission to user, however, I am getting an error that members cannot be removed from distinct channels.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple options to achieve this:

- Remove the channel server-side (this makes sense if the conversation
  is over for both)
- Hide the conversation for one user (see `channel.hide`). Doing so will hide the conversation for one user until a new message is added.